# CodeCademy Codebit document.getElementById() cannot be a variable

Tags: javascript

Ok, I go into a codebit to have fun, and already, about 30 seconds in, something's wrong. I have an div with the id of "main" and when the window loads, will start the program.

HTML:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'>
</script>
<script src='script.js'></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

JS:

```
var x = document.getElementById('main');
function loaded() {
    x.innerHTML ="willnotload!"
}
$(document).ready(function() {loaded();});
```

Don't say "YOU DIDN'T LOAD THE DOCUMENT, ARE YOU STUPID?" like I always get, because doing it without a variable *works*.

Comment: What's the error and is it is error or error by codecademy

Answer (score 2):

You're running the selector before the DOM is ready so the div you're looking for doesn't exist at that time - see what your `x` is.

To fix it, move the `var x = document.getElementById('main');` part inside the loaded function.

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="main">` is not available when your code is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is insert your X variable inside of your jQuery function like so

```
function loaded() {
var x = document.getElementById('main');
    x.innerHTML ="willnotload!"
}
$(document).ready(function() {loaded();});
```

Basically your X variable is being set before the DOM is ready, so X would be null at that point, so when you try to access innerHTML it doesn't exist and nothing will happen :(